# Can I configure CSS grid to lay out cells vertically first, based on the columns count and items count?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid that has 4 columns.

I don't know the count of items to be placed there. I get that from an API.

I'm using Tailwind CSS. This is my style:

```
grid grid-cols-4 gap-4
```

However, when it fills the rows, it fills them horizontally:

- First row

  - First column
  - Second column
  - Third column
  - Fourth column
- Second row

  - First column
  - ...

However, I want it to be filled this way (vertically first)

- First column

  - First row
  - Second row
  - Third row
  - Forth row
  - Nth row that is calculated automatically
- Second column

  - First row
  - Second row
  - ...

I tried [Grid auto flow](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-auto-flow), but none did that for me. Is it possible at all? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: How would the nth row be calculated? For CSS grid column flow to work, there needs to be a defined amount of rows at some point.

Comment: @Wongjn, the browser would automatically calculate it. If you know the number of columns which I have given, and the number of items which is the children count, then it's a simple division to find out the number of rows. Do I miss something here?

Comment: I'm not quite clear. Are you able to use JS to set up the row count (which is a simple calculation based on that number you get from the API) or not?

Comment: @Bigboy Yes, you are missing something there. Grid auto row flow works as there is a defined number of columns, thus inversely, grid auto column flow can only work if there is a defined number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot use JS to set the number of rows, you might look at this rather ugly solution.

You can use `column-4` without grid, although this also has limitations. The browser tries to spread the content evenly over the four columns. This means that if one cell has more content then the other, the rows will not be of equal height and the table will be a mess.

To make rows stay only one line high, you can add `whitespace-nowrap overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden` to each cell.

[Example in tailwind playground.](https://play.tailwindcss.com/U9Chgz3TMe)

```
<div class="columns-4 gap-0 border w-10/12 mx-auto mt-8">
  <div class="whitespace-nowrap overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden border">row 1 col 1</div>
  <div class="whitespace-nowrap overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden border">row 2 col 1</div>
  <div class="whitespace-nowrap overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden border">row 3 col 1 this is a large piece of data that will do mess with the table if the overflow-hidden and nowrap is not set.</div>
  <div class="whitespace-nowrap overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden border">row 4 col 1</div>
  <div class="whitespace-nowrap overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden border">row 1 col 2</div>
  <div class="whitespace-nowrap overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden border">row 2 col 2</div>
  <div class="whitespace-nowrap overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden border">row 3 col 2</div>
  <div class="whitespace-nowrap overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden border">row 4 col 2</div>
  <div class="whitespace-nowrap overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden border">row 1 col 3</div>
  <div class="whitespace-nowrap overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden border">row 2 col 3</div>
  <div class="whitespace-nowrap overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden border">row 3 col 3</div>
  <div class="whitespace-nowrap overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden border">row 4 col 3</div>
  <div class="whitespace-nowrap overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden border">row 1 col 4</div>
  <div class="whitespace-nowrap overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden border">row 2 col 4</div>
  <div class="whitespace-nowrap overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden border">row 3 col 4</div>
  <div class="whitespace-nowrap overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden border">row 4 col 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: A perfect solution. The `columns-4` was what I was looking for. Thank you so much.